responsive h-full by size prime flex
I'm currently using PrimeNg and PrimeFlex in an Angular project, but I'm having trouble using the h-full property because I want it to be used when a card is more than n pixels and when I don't disable it. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

You can use NgClass, and a function to get the card size, in the function you check if the condition met and return true or false, then the ngClass add the class 'h-full'

Here is an example https://angular-2mujj9.stackblitz.io

You’re looking to apply ngClass Angular.dev - ngClass. This will allow you to conditionally set a css class to an element.
You can access this element by using @ViewChild Angular.dev - ViewChild to get the pixel size of the card. Then you can set a boolean flag whether the ngClass should be applied.
